# JPOS Q2 client. Change port on-a-fly

Tags: jpos

Is there any way to change host port for a Q2 client not from a deploy file? I implement a server that listnes for connection on specific port, and I need to send ISO messages to a client(/server) connected to that port and reconnecting from differrent port after 5 minutes. Is it even possible using Q2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMX (try jconsole then you can implement your own JMX client) to force Q2 to reestablish a connection (calling `stop` and then `start`) and it will use a different client port.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion